# Swift Version of Cocos2d Code : sprite1.colorRGBA

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-swift

I used below `cocos2d` code and worked:

```
CCSprite *sprite1 = [[CCSprite alloc] init];
sprite1.position = ccp(SW*0.1f, SH*0.82f);
sprite1.normalMapSpriteFrame = normalMap;
sprite1.effect = glass;
sprite1.colorRGBA = [CCColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.0f];
```

Now tried to port it to Swift, but getting error for `colorRGBA` last line. Help me to get right code.

```
    var sprite1 = CCSprite.node() as CCSprite
    sprite1.position = ccp(SW*0.1, SH*0.82);
    sprite1.normalMapSpriteFrame = normalMap;
    sprite1.effect = glass;
    sprite1.colorRGBA =  ______ ?
```

Comment: What did you enter to get the error?

Comment: Because 0.0f is not valid in Swift use 0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just created a new project with SpriteBuilder in Swift, tried this and all worked:

```
var sprite = CCSprite()    
sprite.colorRGBA = CCColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)
```

Maybe you need to look at [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/4185345) about bridging headers? They will help you to use Objective-C classes in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I did not test this...but you can try

```
sprite1.colorRGBA =  UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)
```